# Search with post_meta

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I write my own query to wordpress database and I'm stuck. I have many (5) custom fields like:

```
town
price
size
... etc
```

and in search.php I have:

```
$querystr = "
SELECT wposts.* 
FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id ";

$town = addslashes($_GET['town']);
if($town!=''){
    $querystr .= " AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'town' AND wpostmeta.meta_value = '".$town."'";
}

$mo = addslashes($_GET['mo']);
if($mo!='' && preg_match("/^\d+$/", $mo)){
    $querystr .= " AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'price' AND wpostmeta.meta_value > '".$mo."'";
}

$md = addslashes($_GET['md']);
if($md!='' && preg_match("/^\d+$/", $md)){
    $querystr .= " AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'price' AND wpostmeta.meta_value < '".$md."'";
}

$querystr .= " AND wposts.post_status = 'publish' AND wposts.post_type = 'post'";

$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
```

but this does not work. If I use only one condition:

```
$querystr = "SELECT wposts.* FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id ";

$town = addslashes($_GET['town']);
if($town!=''){
    $querystr .= " AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'town' AND wpostmeta.meta_value = '".$town."'";
}

$querystr .= " AND wposts.post_status = 'publish' AND wposts.post_type = 'post'";
$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
```

then it will work. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I sugget to `print $querystr;` and see what is wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select expression doesn't make sense as a whole because you have contradictive where conditions. It also doesn't make sense in relation to how relational databases work. You want to match two unique rows that share the same column names in one query, this is not possible without using techniques like [subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html).

Consider that all expression parts must be true and you got something like this:

```
SELECT wposts.*
FROM wp_posts wposts, wp_postmeta wpostmeta
WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'town' AND wpostmeta.meta_value = 'My town' 
AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'price' AND wpostmeta.meta_value > 500
```

Here you say `meta_key` equals "town" AND `meta_value` equals "My town". That makes sense, but when you also say `meta_key` **also** equals "price" AND `meta_value` is **also** greater than 500. The expression will never be true and regardless the parser also has no way of grouping together the two different condition sets.

### WP_Query

If possible I suggest that you use the [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class instead of directly querying the database. This wrapper greatly simplifies your code and makes it easier to maintain. Note that the code requires WordPress >=3.1 as it uses the `meta_query` option.

Your query can be written like this:

```
<?php

// The arguments that defines the query
$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'post'
);

// We define the meta/custom field conditions

$meta_query = array();

// PS: No need to slash the values, WordPress will do that for us
$town = $_GET['town'];
$mo = (int) $_GET['mo']; // Simple sanitizment, implement your own as see fit
$md = (int) $_GET['md']; // Simple sanitizment, implement your own as see fit


if ( $town ) {
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key' => 'town',
        'value' => $town
    );
}

if ( $mo ) {
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key' => 'price',
        'value' => $mo,
        'type' => 'NUMERIC',
        'compare' => '>'
    );
}

if ( $md ) {
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key' => 'price',
        'value' => $md,
        'type' => 'NUMERIC',
        'compare' => '<'
    );
}

if ( $meta_query ) {
    // Add the meta_query conditions to the arguments array

    $meta_query['relation'] = 'AND';

    $args['meta_query'] = $meta_query;
}

// Create WP_Query object with the arguments
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// Fetch the posts
$posts = $query->get_posts();

// Voila!

?>
```